# Text File + JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp

I’m trying to figure out how to include a reference to a external data file (in text form) that I want distributed along with my application via Web Start (JNLP). Sifting through the documentation for the JNLP structure, I see that you can include references to JAR, nativelib, and extensions – however, I don’t see a means to include a text file resource. How can I accomplish this so that Web Start will download the text file from the server and store it locally along with my application?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do that.

You can, however, put it on your classpath (in a jar) and reference it through getResourceAsStream().

Answer (score 0):

i just checked that jnlp file is also available as jar file also and as exe file also, so can i open these in a java gui and load my xml file